# How to check if a button is clicked after 2 secs?

Tags: android, server, delay, android-view

I have an android app which sends likes to the server.

What i want to do is not to send a like to server immediately but send after 2 secs if user still likes the post.

My like void;

```
public void rotationAnimation(ImageView button, int source1, int source2){
    if(isLikeClicked){
        button.setImageResource(source1);
        button.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        isLikeClicked = false;
    }else{
        button.setImageResource(source2);
        button.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        isLikeClicked = true;
    }

    ChangeLikeCount();

    if(isReadyToPost)
        if(!isLikeClicked){
            Like like = new Like();
            like.execute(ServerCons.HOST + "unlike");
        }else{
            Like like = new Like();
            like.execute(ServerCons.HOST + "like");
        }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // I thought the solution could be there
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
boolean isReadyToPost= false;
boolean liked = false;//control like click (witch)

public void onLikePressed() {
  if (liked && isReadyToPost) {
    sendLikeToServer();//send to server after 2 secs
    return;
   }

  this.isReadyToPost= false;
  Toast.makeText(this, "waiting for any dislike... in 2 secs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (liked){
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isReadyToPost=true; 
        onLikePressed();                      
     }
   }, 2000);
 }//end if
} //end onlikepress
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it using `isReadyToPost` flag:

```
if(isReadyToPost){
  isReadyToPost=false;
}else{
  // try after 2 secs for next like
}
```

and in `Handler. postDelayed` change `isReadyToPost` to true after 2 secs:

```
  @Override
    public void run() {
        isReadyToPost=true;
    }
```

`isReadyToPost`  default value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a thread that sleeps for 2 sec and after that it checks if user still likes the post then update your database